# How do you exactly fill out any screen with your website?

Tags: html, css, height

I have the following problem:

I want to create a website where 2 divs fill out the entire screen, no matter what size the screen is. Generally, it works but only if I don't use padding or margin. If I use either one of those the scrollbar shows because of the div's need more space.

I tried to lower the height percentage to accommodate the padding/margin at the top and the bottom. For example, if I had an original size of 70% and I wanted a 5% margin/padding I changed it to 60% but it still couldn't fit the screen.

I know I could just hide the scrollbar but I want the divs to be exact. Is there a way to do this?

In my case, I would like the div with the topper class to be 25% and the div with the lower class to be 75% of the screen.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheet.css">
    <title>Home - Planner</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="topper">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>HOME</h1>
          <hr class="short-hr">
          <h3>Planner</h3>
        </div>
        <hr class="wide-hr">
      </div>
      <div class="lower">
        <div class="card left">
          <h2>Einkaufsliste</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card right">
          <h2>Kalender</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card left">
          <h2>ToDo - List</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card right">
          <h2>Einstellungen</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

* {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.topper {
  height: 25%;
}

.header {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lower {
  height: 75%;
}

.card {
  height: 35%;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  border: 2.5pt solid #000000;
  border-radius: 15pt;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do, is pretty easy to achieve. Simply change the css of your `class .container`. Remove thei height of 100% and give it an absolute position with top, bottom, left and right of 0.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

with that CSS change, the container will take all available space. However note, that such use is a bad habbit as it will only be semi-responsive. you need to have plenty breakpoints to prevent an overflow with small screens.

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.topper {
  height: 25%;
}

.header {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lower {
  height: 75%;
}

.card {
  height: 35%;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  border: 2.5pt solid #000000;
  border-radius: 15pt;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="topper">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>HOME</h1>
      <hr class="short-hr">
      <h3>Planner</h3>
    </div>
    <hr class="wide-hr">
  </div>
  <div class="lower">
    <div class="card left">
      <h2>Einkaufsliste</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card right">
      <h2>Kalender</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card left">
      <h2>ToDo - List</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card right">
      <h2>Einstellungen</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```